# Is a multivariate monotone function quasiconvex?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

More precisely:

A multivariate function $f(x)$, $\mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}$, is monotone increasing if $\forall x,y \in \textbf{dom}$ $f$ if $\forall i, x_i \leq y_i \implies f(x) \leq f(y)$ and similarly for monotone decreasing.

Is such a function always quasiconvex or quasiconcave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false, I came up with the following counterexample:

$f: R^2 \to R$ s.t $f(2,0)=1$, $f(0,2)=1$ and $f(1,1)=2$. For all other points in the $(x,y)$ plane, define $f(x,y)$ to be $0$ if $y < 2-x$ and $f(x,y)=2$ if $y \geq 2-x$ (obviously with the exception of the 3 points i singled out).

Note first that $f$ defined in this way is not quasi-convex, since $f(\frac{1}{2}(2,0)+\frac{1}{2}(0,2))=f(1,1)=2 > \max\{f(2,0),f(0,2)\}=1$ On the other hand $f$ is "monotonic" as per your definition, it's easier to check this graphically I think.

It helped me to draw a point $(c,d)$ in the $x,y$ plane and consider the set of points $(a,b)$ such that $f(a,b) \leq f(x,y)$ because of monotonicity of $f$ these were exactly the points "below" AND to the "left" of $(c,d)$, and this observation helped me make the counterexample.

Comment: Great, thanks for your answer. I wonder why, intuitively, monotonic $\mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ functions are always convex but "monotonic" $\mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ functions are not.

Comment: Because $\mathbb{R}$ is totally ordered. You want to give a proof like: $f$ is quasi-convex if $f(tx+(1-t)y) \leq \max \{x,y\}$ for all $x,y$ $t \in [0,1]$. Fix $x "\leq " y$, i.e $x_i \leq y_i$ for all $i$, then by "monotonicity" we have $f(x) \leq f(y)$, so to show quasi-convexity we need $f(tx+(1-t)y) \leq f(y)$, by monotonicity of $f$ its enough that $tx_i+(1-t)y_i \leq y_i$, but indeed by assumption $x_i \leq y_i$ so $tx_i+(1-t)y_i \leq ty_i+(1-t)y_i=y_i$ and we're done. Unfortunately in $R^n$ we have $x "\leq" y$ is a rare thing, no reason to expect it will happen.

Comment: But you can say, let $f: R^n \to R$ be monotonic if $|x| \leq |y|$ implies $f(x) \leq f(y)$, and then indeed the proof goes through and you get quasi-convexity (not this notion of monotonicity does not depend coordinate by coordinate, in the previous case in $R^2$ you have $(1,10000000)$ is not greater than $(2,1)$, despite being much further from the origin. In my definition, as you go "out" in a general sense you get larger. Try proving in $R^2$ that if you draw any line segment, one of the two endpoints is necessarily further from the origin than any other point on the segment.