# Quasiconcave, Continuous, Monotone Functions

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

In [another thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1886519/is-a-multivariate-monotone-function-quasiconvex) a fellow user found a counter example to a monotonic multivariate function that is not quasi concave.

My question: if we add a continuity assumption - is any continuous, monotonic (gradient greater than 0) multivariate function quasi concave?

Thank you!

Comment: Note that the term *gradient* makes only sense if your function has partial derivatives. I assume you want to use the same definition as in the old post instead.

Answer (score 0):

If I took the right definitions then

$$f(x,y) = \max\{x,y\}$$

might be a counterexample.